# iOS virtual button to Arduino

Tags: ios, ipad, arduino, wireless, xbee

What would be the best way of sending a signal from an iPad to an Arduino?

I am trying to use [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digi_International#Wireless), with iPad and Arduino to send a wireless signal.
I want to make a big red virtual button on an iPad that, when pressed, turns on an LED on the Arduino.
I am a total newbie when it comes to iOS, but OK with Arduino and XBee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but in my meaning there is only one simple way to solve the problem:

Connect an XBee to a Computer and another to the Arduino. On the computer you launch a webserver, which will be accesible from the iPad over Safari. This server handles the clickes and writes to the XBee Com Port, for communication.

Here are some examples, people already made:

- http://www.projectallusion.com/1/post/2009/11/iphone-controlled-solar-powered-arduino-tank.html
- http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/152 (not with xbee, but you can implement that by yourself)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while but I just came across to this question and yesterday I was doing the exact same thing so I'll share the method I used and the source of it.

In order to set a LED on or off in an Arduino board from the iPad you really don't need anything more than a browser.  This is of course if you have a way to connect that Arduino to the local network.

Today you have at least two options.  The WiFi and the Ethernet shields.  Once you have your Arduino board inside the network you can send the instructions (HIGH or LOW) to the board form the browser.

These are my two boards connected waiting to be plugged to the local network:

[image: Arduino Uno + Ethernet Shield]

Of course, you'll have to code the board to process those instructions. There are many examples on how to configure network settings and state instructions:

[image: Arduino IDE with code for the Web Server]

If you have a bit of time and want to do something more elaborated you could create a simple app to graphically control the state of those LED(s).

[image: Simple storyboard of an Arduino Uno board to control LEDs from the App]

Inside you'll basically do the same thing, create the URL command and send it to the Arduino IP but it'd look much nicer.  If you integrate later more controls the sky in the limit.

My experiment is a combination of what I learned from this nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15932/electronics-for-iphone-developers-tutorial-control-a-led-from-your-iphone) and some tips I've read here and there.

I hope it becomes also useful to someone else.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use a network connection from the iPad, a possibly simpler way to do this would be to use a WiFi module on the Arduino to poll a web script, and have the iPad write a state (button press) to that web script.

There's a handy WiFi module called the RN-XV that's designed like an XBee.  I wrote up two tutorials on it:

- http://log.liminastudio.com/programming/getting-started-with-the-rn-xv-wifi-module-node-js
- http://log.liminastudio.com/itp/physical-computing/using-the-rn-xv-wifi-module-as-a-remote-switch